# How to print out to screen in rspec integration test in rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

We want to print out some variables to the screen during integration test. `pp` and `puts` were not doing anything. Is there other command we can use in rspec to print out to screen in integration test (use capybara)? Thanks.

Comment: we have to require 'pp' in integration test first, then pp prints out.

Comment: `puts` should work, and you don't think you need to have your output format as `documentation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `puts`.

Make sure your rspec output format is `documentation`. Command like

```
rspec --format documentation
```

Or set that in `.rspec`